# dashDB API call fails

Tags: curl, ibm-cloud, dashdb

I have created and interacted with a dashDB instance in IBM Bluemix through the web application but when I try the following curl command, from the dashDB API [documentation](https://developer.ibm.com/static/site-id/85/api/dashdb-analytics/#/) :

```
curl --user "[userid]:[password]" -X GET "https://[hostname]:[port]/dashdb-api/home"
```

I get this error:

```
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to <hostname>:50000
```

In this context, what does this error mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I have been using the wrong port in the hostname, the dashDB port is listed to be 5000 but because this call is https the port should be 8443.

Comment: The dashDB data service ports are 50000 (non-SSL) and 50001 (SSL), whereas the console port is 8443.  As you noticed, It's the console that processes the REST API calls made.